# Longitud unica de segmentos de una linea

Tags: c#, algoritmos

Estoy tratando de obtener la distancia recorrida en una colección de recorridos en linea recta. La regla para determinar la distancia es que solo cuentan los tramos único, si paso mas de una vez solo cuenta la primera.
Ejemplo:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Tramo ║ Desde ║ Hasta ║
╠═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║     1 ║   100 ║   110 ║
║     2 ║   115 ║   116 ║
║     3 ║   100 ║   111 ║
║     4 ║     0 ║    15 ║
║     5 ║    50 ║   110 ║
║     6 ║    70 ║   120 ║
╚═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

En estos recorridos la distancia única fue de 85m. Realice una solución que utiliza un bit array para control, y un contador para calcular la distancia, esto la velocidad y el consumo de memoria hasta 20250000 metros es bueno, el rendimiento decae. Podrian recomendar me algún algoritmo para resolver este tipo de problema?

---

### Actualización, otro ejemplo de un problema similar

Un problema similar es para la unión de distintos conjunto de números enteres, de los cuales solo tenemos el inicio y el fin para cada conjunto, se desee conocer la cantidad de números resultado de la unión de estos:

El conjunto P son numero desde exclusive el 0 hasta el 15,  el conjunto Q es de números desde exclusive el 11 hasta el 15, y el conjunto R es desde exclusive el 14 hasta el 20, la unión de estos conjuntos da un nuevo grupo de 20 elementos únicos.

---

Nota estas distancia son en linea recta, no son rutas que posean georeferencia, sino que son segmentos de una linea recta.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public class MainClass {
    static Estacion[] estaciones = new Estacion[]{
          new Estacion(100,110),
          new Estacion(115,116),
          new Estacion(100,111),
          new Estacion(0,15),
          new Estacion(50,110),
          new Estacion(70,120)
      };

  public static void Main (string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine (Calcular());
  }

  public static int Calcular()
  {

    var min =estaciones.Min(m=> m.Desde);
    var max =estaciones.Max(m=> m.Hasta);

    var recorrido =0;
    var cantidad= max-min;
    var bA = new BitArray(cantidad,false);
    foreach(var e in estaciones.OrderByDescending(o=> o.Longitud))
    {
      var h= ((e.Hasta-e.Desde)/2);
      for(int i= 0;i<= h ; i++)
      {
        var slot=i+e.Desde-min;
        if(slot<cantidad)  
        if(!bA.Get(slot))
        {
           bA.Set(slot,true);
          recorrido++;
        }
        slot=e.Hasta-i-min-1;
        if(!bA.Get(slot)) 
        {
           bA.Set(slot,true);
          recorrido++;
        }
        if(recorrido== cantidad)
          return recorrido;
      }
    }
    return recorrido;
  }

  public class Estacion
  {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int Desde {get; set;}
    public int Hasta {get; set;}
    public int Longitud {get; set;}

    public Estacion(int a, int b)
    {
      Desde = a;
      Hasta= b;
      Longitud= Hasta-Desde;
      Id= Guid.NewGuid();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicar de una forma mas detallada el problema en lo  personal confude un poco.

Comment: Otro ejemplo pude ser hay una lista de rangos de números, los que se ven en la tabla, ocupas saber cuantos elementos únicos hay en la union de todos esos rangos, para este ejemplo hay 85 ya q los elementos repetidos solo se cuentan una vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publique esta pregunta tambien en [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174602/single-segment-length-of-a-line) y amablemente la comunidad me brindo una respuesta

> 1. Ordenar los intervalos por la posición de inicio de forma ascendente, y por la posición donde termina de forma descendente.
> 2. Iniciarla el intervalo anterior con el primer intervalo y el total en 0.
> 3. Iterar desde el segundo elemento hasta el ultimo y en cada iteración:
> 4. Si el intervalo actual esta contenido en el anterior, ignorar este.
> 5. Si el intervalo actual traslapa con el anterior, actualizar o remplazar el intervalo anterior para incluir completamente ambos.
> 6. Si el intervalo previo no se traslapa con el previo, agregar el tamaño del intervalo actual al total y remplazar el intervalo anterior por el previo .

Esta seria la implementación de esas instrucciones

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class MainClass
{
    static Estacion[] estaciones = new Estacion[] { new Estacion(100, 110), new Estacion(115, 116), new Estacion(100, 111), new Estacion(0, 15), new Estacion(50, 110), new Estacion(70, 120), new Estacion(0, 20250000) };
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Calcular());
    }

    public static int Calcular()
    {
        var min = estaciones.Min(m => m.Desde);
        var max = estaciones.Max(m => m.Hasta);
        var total = 0;        
        Estacion estacionActual = null;
        foreach (var item in estaciones.OrderBy(o => o.Desde).ThenByDescending(o => o.Hasta))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            if (estacionActual == null)
            {
                estacionActual = item;
                total = item.Longitud;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((estacionActual.Desde <= item.Desde) && (item.Desde <= estacionActual.Hasta) && (estacionActual.Hasta < item.Hasta))
                {
                    total += item.Hasta - estacionActual.Hasta;
                    estacionActual.Hasta = item.Hasta;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((estacionActual.Desde < item.Desde) && (estacionActual.Hasta < item.Desde))
                    {
                        total += item.Hasta - item.Desde;
                        estacionActual = item;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return total;
    }

    public class Estacion
    {
        public Guid Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Desde
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Hasta
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Longitud
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Estacion(int a, int b)
        {
            Desde = a;
            Hasta = b;
            Longitud = Hasta - Desde;
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0},{1}", Desde, Hasta);
        }
    }
}
```